# override default image file for product via module

Tags: product

i want to use my custom media.phtml for products , how can i do it instead of changing media.phtml , i am new here can u please tell how can i do it via module.

i want that my module should use custom media.phtml that i created so that my chnages do not get lost on theme update

Answer (score 2):

Add this to the layout xml file of your module:

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info.media">
         <action method="setTemplate">
             <template>path.to/your/template.phtml</template>
         </action>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```